# Editing Facebook comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a website for a friend using Adobe Business Catalyst.

I have inserted the code for facebook like and facebook comments into the sidebar of the webpages. Like is working but the comments behaviour is not what I expected.

To moderate comments my understanding is that I need to insert the FB moderator meta tags on the URL specified as the href parameter and they need to be included in the head tag of the web page. I am using my friends facebook user ID as the moderator. My understanding is that the facebook ID is the 15 digit no at the end of the URL in the facebook homepage.

The guidance I have read says you should be able to moderate comments "inline". My questions;

1. I have inserted the meta tags with my friends Facebook User ID into the Header Tags of the web template I am using. Is this correct ?  How exactly do you do this it does not seem to be working !
2. How exactly do I access FB comments and edit inline ?
3. When I insert comments using my wife's FB ID they save on the website when I use my friends ID who I am creating the site for they do not save on the website ? Is this a setting issue ?

I am new to this so I am probably missing something basic here but any advice greatly appreciated. I have been reading guidance in Stackoverflow and the FB developers site.

Kind Regards. Shelly&Matt.